# Android FCM requirements on Android device

Tags: java, android, firebase, cloud, google-play-services

I successfully implemented Firebase Cloud Messaging in my Android app. But I am not sure about the requirements to be met by the Android device for receiving notifications, like Android version, Google play store and Google Account.

Can anyone tell me about such requirements?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen [HERE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) you should have google services 3.0+, and running on Android 4.0+